# list.append or list +=?

Tags: python

Which is more pythonic?

```
list.append(1)
```

or

```
list += [1]
```

Answer (score 63):

`list.append(1)` is faster, because it doesn't create a temporary list object.

Comment: +1 - Both the answer and explanation are good.  Succinct and to the point. Thanks.

Comment: Wasn't the question "which is more pythonic?"

Comment: List object creation is beside the point. Besides, (:-) CPython will reuse a list from its empty list in this case.

Comment: @ojrac: What is faster is often what is more Pythonic, as the Python devs tend to optimize behaviors they encourage.

Comment: And "which is more pythonic?" was the question. The word "faster" is totally off-topic unless there's a serious issue with either approach, which there is not.

Answer (score 57):

From the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Explicit is better than implicit.

So: `list.append(1)`

Comment: is `list += list` not explicit?

Comment: IMO, operators are less explicit function names.

Comment: As an example for operators being less explicit than named functions: what does 'list += list' mean? Reading it, i could think appending, but I could also think you might want to add the values in a list of numerical values (e.g. [1, 2, 3] += [4, 5, 6] => [5, 7, 9] could make sense).

Comment: You might also think that `[1,2] += [3] => [1,2,[3]]`

Answer (score 17):

These are two different operations, what you are doing with += is the extend operation. Here is what Python documents have to say about this:

> list.append(x): Add an item to the end of the list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = [x].
>
> list.extend(L): Extend the list by appending all the items in the given list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = L.

So in += you provide a list, in append you just add a new element.

Answer (score 8):

While most people here are preferring the append option, I personally prefer the other one because it looks nicer even though it may be slower (or maybe its optimized).

> Beautiful is better than ugly.

When you write lots of Python code, I don't usually see something like this:

```
list.append(1)
```

It's more like this:

```
somecollectionname.append(anotherelementname+5*10)
```

So to me at least, it is nicer to see:

```
somecollectionname += [anotherelementname+5*10]
```

Because its easy to recognize at a glance that you are adding to a list. Having said that, I sometimes find myself using both forms.

Answer (score 7):

Since there's also

```
list.extend(l)
```

which appends all elements of the given list, I would use

```
list.append(1)
```

for symmetry and readability's sake.

Comment: I personally keep confusing myself with the difference between `extend()` and `append()`. Therefore, had the question been about some list `lst` rather than a fixed single element `1`, my answer would have been: `+=` is better because then I am sure the left and right operand are peers and we are talking about a concatenation here, not an *add the whole list as the last element*.

Answer (score 4):

list.append(1)
more readable and to consistent with the context

Answer (score 4):

If you've got a single element, `a`, that you want to add to your list `l`, then putting `a` into its own list and extending `l` with it seems like adding unnecessary complexity. I would thus prefer

```
l.append(a)
```

over

```
l += [a]
```

If `a` is already a list, then choosing

```
l += a
```

or

```
l.extend(a)
```

is a matter of preference, IMO. On the other hand, if you're going to be doing a lot of extends, you can get a performance boost by "hoisting" the method lookup:

```
extend = l.extend
for sublist in bunch_of_lists:
    extend(sublist)
```

Finally, I think that the append operation isn't used too often in Pythonic code, because append is used very often in "accumulator" idioms, where I'd expect a more experienced Python programmer to use a list comprehension/etc.

So instead of:

```
l = []
for a in numbers:
    l.append(str(a))
```

You'd probably see:

```
l = [str(a) for a in numbers]
```

or

```
l = map(str, numbers)
```

Comment: You surely you `map(str, numbers)` ?

Answer (score 1):

### Beware of fundamentalism

Have you noticed the term "more pythonic" in your question?
I think it implies that you are asking a not-so-helpful question.

If one is merely *more* pythonic than the other (rather than being 
pythonic while the other is not) it could be said that you have
violated the Zen of Python on a meta level:
*"Simple is better than complex"* should also hold for the
process of searching for the form in which you express
your logic -- once you have found something pythonic,
that is good enough. Keep the search simple.

So my answer would be:
Neither of them is more pythonic.
**The most pythonic thing is to go on and write a nice program.**